# Installing R on RHEL

Tags: linux, package-management

Hi I'm trying to install R on this RHEL 8 machine, I have been trying to check a lot of other answers but none of them seem to be helping. I am listing my code and errors below

[ec2-user@`]$ cat /etc/redhat-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.1 (Ootpa)

[ec2-user@`]$ sudo yum install -y R

Updating Subscription Management repositories. 
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:34:31 ago on Tue 19 Nov 2019 06:59:37 AM UTC.

Error:

Problem: package R-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 requires R-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7, but none of the providers can be installed

- package R-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 requires R-core-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7, but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
- nothing provides texinfo-tex needed by R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64

(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Comment: "Unable to read consumer identity This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register." Fix this first.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

The problem was that the system was not under red had subscription management.

Fixed that problem and now the installations are working like a charm